# VS2019: Include file as project macro

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, preprocessor, propertysheet

I got a makefile project for Linux and I want to compile it on Win10 with Visual Studio 2019.
There are some paths to files defined in the makefile as preprocessor defines.

I have to replace the paths by own created files because they are a kind of PLATFORM_HEADER and I have to adapt a new one to Windows. In the code it looks like:

```
#include PLATFORM_HEADER
```

The onliest I tried is to add a property sheet to my project and add a macro:
[macro page of property sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkjWR.png) But this macro is not found in the project.

Changing the code is not possible because it is third party code and it must be able to become updated at later times without doing changes again.

In other instructions there is noted that a line called 'inherited property sheet' has to be modified in the project. But in VS2019 this line does not exist.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem will be handled by your compiler suite. Probably you'll deal this with your build process manager (make, bitbake, cmake...). You can ask it to pass these #defines as argument for the compilation ([-D name=definition](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)).

Now you've unlocked the "very most of fun" if you compile something meant for linux on windows since there are many way that can go wrong. You might want to do a full check of your environment variable when compiling and make sure they point to the right system librairies.

Probably it's worth giving a try to the windows subsystem for linux and other bindings / emulator. If you want to preview a week of work's outcome, maybe you can do it in a linux VM? or just get rid of windows one good time for all :)